# Unable to delete a zip file in java

Tags: java, zip, delete-file

I am uploading few zip files from a directory to a server and after successful upload I am deleting all these zip files.

When I comment my Upload code delete works fine, but when I uncomment the upload code, deleting the zip files fail.

I have referred various questions from SO but none of them helped.

Can someone please help me with the issue, below is my code,

**UploadCode**

```
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("log.txt");
        ChannelSftp ccha = null;
        Session se = null;
        try {
            JSch s = new JSch();
            se = s.getSession("user", "hostname", 22);
            se.setPassword("passwd");
            se.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            se.connect();
            ccha = (ChannelSftp)se.openChannel("sftp");
            ccha.connect();
            ccha.cd("dummy");

            File folder = new File("folders");
            int count = 1;

            for(File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                try {
                    ccha.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());
                    try {
                        ccha.ls(file.getName());
                        System.out.println("success");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("fail");
                        fw.append("failed for - " + file.getName() + " -- " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    fw.append("Error" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            fw.append("session error " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
        finally {
            fw.close();
            ccha.disconnect();
            se.disconnect();
        }
```

**DeleteCode**

```
    File f = new File(path);
    if(f.isDirectory()) {
        ArrayList<String> allFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        getFiles(f, files); //A simple recursive function which returns all the files in the folder
        for(String fpath : files)
            new File(fpath).delete();
        f.delete();
    }
    else
        f.delete();
```

Any reference on this would also be of great help !

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `getFiles(f, allFiles)`?

Comment: @daniu is right. Is it a typo in posting the question or you are doing this ?

Comment: i have modified my code and posted with dummy names..forgot to change that specific variable..edited the question..thanks :)

Comment: @Kayaman can you please  let me know which resource should i close ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing your resources properly. You open a file for reading but never close it at

`ccha.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());`

This can prevent the file from being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ForceDelete](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileDeleteStrategy.html). Add [apache-common](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) dependency.

Try with ths:

```
File f = new File(path);

    Arrays.stream(f.listFiles()).forEach(file->{
        try{
            FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(file);
        }catch (Exception ex){
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks..but if possible can you please tell me why my code is failing ?

Comment: if your file is processing by another then you can not delete